# How to activate keyboard with button?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, keyboard, ionic-framework

I'm new with this.
I'm doing android (in future also and iOS) application with Phonegap. I would like that my keyboard opens when I tap on some button and closes also with button. I add ionic keyboard plug from https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard and button in html:

```
<div class="button">
             <button id="open_keyb">Click Me!</button>
         </div>
```

and javascript :

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        alert(1);
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show();
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

  app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if(window.cordova){
            cordova.plugins && cordova.plugins.Keyboard && cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        alert('test');
    });
});

app.directive('input', function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            'returnClose': '=',
            'onReturn': '&',
            'onFocus': '&',
            'onBlur': '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            element.bind('focus', function(e){
                if(scope.onFocus){
                    $timeout(function(){
                        scope.onFocus();
                    });
                }
            });
            element.bind('blur', function(e){
                if(scope.onBlur){
                    $timeout(function(){
                        scope.onBlur();
                    });
                }
            });
            element.bind('keydown', function(e){
                if(e.which == 13){
                    if(scope.returnClose) element[0].blur();
                    if(scope.onReturn){
                        $timeout(function(){
                            scope.onReturn();
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
 .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
    ionic.Platform.isFullScreen = true;
  });
})

var fn = function() {

    alert('test');
    document.getElementById('one').onclick = function() {
        alert('click');
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show();
    };

};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn, false);
```

in www folder.
And this is not working. This alerts aren't showing also. Can you help me? How to make this working?

Comment: If you really plan to make your application with Phonegap, you should definitely start with learning JavaScript. There are a lot of syntax errors here, and if you can't identify them right now, you're gonna ask a lot of questions here.

Comment: I didn't cheched for that syntax errors, i copied that from internet. I have only wrote the last function : var fn = function() and  I think that is ok. I will check for the others, thanks for advice ;)

Comment: Wait a second, what is not working? what is the part you actually did and the one you copied? the button can't of course be working, its ID is `open_keyb` while every single listener is being added to other IDs. Also, you don't really need to declare fn, you can just keep this part of code aside of the fn function.

Comment: What did you try to do whith `.run(function($ionicPlatform) {` ? (line 81)
It is a call to a `run` method, but on which object ?
Your `var app` does not have any `run` method. (check https://github.com/mhartington/Ionic-Chat/blob/master/www/js/app.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no event listener is being added to the `open_keyb` button, therefore nothing will fire.

Moreover, since it looks like you're working with mobile devices, you may be want to add the `touchend` event too, despite the `click` should be working in any case.

Please try replacing:

```
var fn = function() {

    alert('test');
    document.getElementById('one').onclick = function() {
        alert('click');
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show();
    };

};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn, false);
```

with this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(DOMLoaded){
   document.getElementById('open_keyb').addEventListener('click', function (clickEvent){
       alert('click');
       cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show();
   });
});
```

Comment: thank you for your efforts to explain and on understanding for my incompetence. This does not work, i.e. I think that it do not pull this javascript code ever.

Comment: There must be some other problems somewhere then, since in this basic fiddle it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/ufq8gghc/ where did you get the very first script from? (the cordova part)

Comment: i took that from http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/chat-tutorial-using-beta3-epic/3848